# Cortex R5 - Startup code

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, arm, gnu

What is to be included in the startup and the linker file for cortex r5 processor?
What are the exact steps that we need to follow after a reset has been given to the processor?
(Specific to cortex r5)
Any idea how to do this for GNU-GCC for arm?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "startup", what are you thinking of. From RESET of the processor, to "main" of your program is quite a lot of steps, hundreds, if not thousands of lines of code - not counting code to initialize devices that aren't essential to making the processor itself work. Describing that as an answer is definitely beyond me - and I think it's beyond the SO basic premise.

Comment: I've definitely used cstartup code that is more like 50 lines of code.  Pretty simple stuff like zeroing bss, copying initialized data variables, maybe writing a pattern to the stack.

Comment: for C it is dozens or fewer lines of code, C++ and other languages perhaps want more.  For C with gcc it is a fairly trivial task (included in the crt0.S that is already there but that has to mate with the included linker script they are tightly married).

Comment: It is a programming question, vector tables, SO is definitely the right place for this question.  Doesnt mean this is a well written or researched question (you didnt include what you have found and tried so far, where you looked and what part of it you dont understand).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download [DS-5](http://ds.arm.com/downloads/) which claims to contain Cortex R5 bare-metal startup code (I didn't check that myself).

From DS-5's [changelog](http://ds.arm.com/developer-resources/ds-5-development-studio-changelog/)

> > Examples: bare-metal start-up code added for the Cortex-R5(F) processor, including vector table, exception handlers, MPU, caches, TCM and VFP initialization, based on the Versatile Express R5x2 platform: startup_Cortex-R5